# Replicate Google's "I'm Feeling Lucky" Button On My Own Site -- To Take User to Top Search Result Automatically

Tags: html, response.redirect

I am trying to replicate Google's I'm feeling lucky button.

But when I click the button it takes me to " Redirect Notice" page.

My code is as below:

```
<form action="https://google.com/search">
    <input type="text" name="q">
    <input type="submit" value="Google Search">
    <input type="submit" name = btnI value="I'm Feeling Lucky">
</form>
```

Comment: what is `name = btnI` exactly supposed to be? it's a typo?

Comment: Are you sure you can have 2 type submit in one form ? just a question...

Answer (score 4):

**TLDR:** Just use DuckDuckGo.  You typically don't care about what search engine is doing the redirecting, so long as you land on the top-result for a search term and the page for that result loads (and not a redirect page of the search engine).

> https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%5Csoybeans

This URL above will redirect to...

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soybean

The `%5c` code above is the indicator for loading the page directly without search results (similar to the `BtnI` of Google).

**Details on the Redirect Page from Linking to Google's "I'm Feeling Lucky"**

- Oct. 2, 2019: The redirect page was first reported on [Google Search Help](https://support.google.com/websearch/thread/15794018?hl=en), the question has since been closed and comments are disabled -- they are probably not going to fix this.
- You cannot use an `<iframe />`.  Loading `<iframe src="https://www.google.com/" />` has always loaded blank for me for the past ten years.
- Likewise, you cannot use `XMLHttpRequest`, which I just tried, because CORS will block you out, and most browsers do not allow `XMLHttepRequest.setHeader("origin", "http://www.google.com/");`, otherwise, you could simply get the redirect page, parse for the first URL, and load that page.  We ***know*** this is the case, because doing this following in a terminal will bypass the redirect page ([thanks to Metamorphic for discovering this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/114543)):

  ```
  w3m -header "Referer: http://www.google.com/" "https://www.google.com/search?btnI=1&q=soybeans"
  ```

Iframes don't work, XmlHttpRequest doesn't work, and the main post on the Google Search forums for this topic has been closed and locked.  I think it's obvious you'll need to find a different approach -- i.e., like a different search engine.

Answer (score -1):

> The %5c code above is the indicator for loading the page directly
> without search results (similar to the BtnI of Google).

I've been looking all over the place for this, thank you!